# Typing website highlighted letters

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm in the middle of a project, which is about a typing website. I've made a virtual keyboard with only div tags. Also, I'm going to have a area with letters, which they will be the typing text. In the next step, i want every key to be highlighted in the letters-area and in the virtual keyboard at the same time. I am really stuck on this. I have thought of some ideas, but none of these do what I want.

Any ideas would be extremely helpful!

Comment: so you want the random letter that they are supposed to type to be highlighted on the keyboard?

Comment: can you show us what you have so far

Comment: in the keyboard and in the textarea at the same time.

Comment: Can you draw us a pretty picture?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/gqh2c9m8hd1lz87/keyboard.php

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to look into the Javascript `keydown` event handler.

Here's a quick example that may put you in the right directon.

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownEvent, false);

function keyDownEvent(e) {
var keyCode = e.keyCode;
  if(keyCode==13) {
     //enter was pressed...
     //highlight the relevant keyboard div.
  }
}
```

EDIT:
If you don't want to add a case to your program for every single keycode on a keyboard, then I suggest taking a look at [this](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes) webpage for relevant character keycodes and then naming your divs with an ID relevant to the keycode.

For example:
'J' is KeyCode: 74. So my div would have the following id:

```
<div id="keycode_74"></div>
```

Obviously you'd need to add logic to see if the div exists on the page, but I'll leave this up to you as I don't want to code the entire solution for you :)

Comment: thanks for the response. but in this solution, i have to check every time for every letter??

Comment: If you don't want to add a case for every letter, see my updated answer :)

Comment: hmmm yes thats the good idea. but if i name every letter with something like that "key_code74", i think that i will again have check for every letter. one solution in my mind is that every key of my virtual keyboard to have id the charCode. what do u think??

Comment: Yeah that's what I meant :) In the example I just added the prefix of 'keycode_' as the id attribute. You'll still need to add extra JS validation to check if the element exists within the DOM, but I guess this is way easier than having a huge chunk of JS code for each keycode case.

Comment: okay! i think you put me on the right road. thanks very much

Comment: No worries. You can accept this answer by clicking on the green tick :)